# Should I test all methods with Integration Tests?

Tags: java, integration-testing

I have a doubt about integration tests, for example:

I have a class called Service, and Service has three methods:

```
public doSomething();
protected retriableUpdate();
protected update();
```

The method doSomething() is public, and the others are called from it, but only the update() is the method when the integration actually occurs.

So, in a integration test scenario, should I have to test only doSomething(), only update() or all the three methods?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Unit tests should test all three of them individually. Integration tests should only test the outward-facing functionality (you're testing the  _system_, not _individual classes_).

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy so, for example, when testing an S3 upload document, on my IT I have to test the method when occurs the upload/delete, in case of databases I have to test only the method that, in fact, query on that database. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Being it an integration test or a unit test it does not really matter. You should only test your public methods and avoid testing other methods directly. They should be tested via the tests of the public methods.

The difference between integration and unit tests is that usually, you want the unit tests to test the most if not all your business logic while with integration tests you might consider testing only the more important / complicated use cases. The reason is that an integration test is harder to set up and slower to run than a unit test, so usually, you would want to have a larger number of unit tests. There is even a thing called The Test Pyramid that shows you how much of which test type you should consider having in your code ("Service Tests" == "Integration Tests"):

[image]

*(taken from https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html)*